# Could Not File: Corda Crash Shell during Gradle Build

Tags: corda

We are using artifactory to connect through a firewall to the internet. When running **./gradlew clean build** we get the following exception message:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':java-source:testCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.corda.crash:crash.shell:9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716.
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://code-artifacts.bankofamerica.com:18081/artifactory/virtual-java/com/github/corda/crash/crash.shell/9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716/crash.shell-9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716.pom
      http://code-artifacts.bankofamerica.com:18081/artifactory/virtual-java/com/github/corda/crash/crash.shell/9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716/crash.shell-9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716.jar
  Required by:
      project :java-source > net.corda:corda-node-driver:1.0.0 > net.corda:corda-test-utils:1.0.0 > net.corda:corda-node:1.0.0
```

We are wondering if the version number of crash.shell is having an affect on jar lookup.

Answer (score 0):

In Corda V1.0, `net.corda:corda-node:1.0.0` lists `com.github.corda.crash:crash.shell:9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716` as a compile dependency. This corresponds to https://github.com/corda/crash/tree/9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716/shell.

If you are behind a firewall and this dependency isn't present in your artifactory, the build will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is now in the R3 corda-dependencies repo so you just need to update your `build.gradle`:

```
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases' }
    maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-dependencies' }
  }
```